# String or binary data would be truncated on time input to database

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

How do I get the current time and input it into SQL server. There is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Audit](
    [PK_Audit] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SequenceNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TableName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [RunDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [StartTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [EndTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Status] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ProcessName] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [InsertCount] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UpdateCount] [int] NULL,
    [DeleteCount] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Audit] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PK_Audit] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

I am trying to use calander to get the time and input it into the database:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
java.util.Date start = cal.getTime();
```

To me it looked like you need to convert it to something SQL understands so I did the following:

```
audit.setDate(4, new java.sql.Date(start.getTime()));
```

When I execute the query I get the following error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: String or binary data would be truncated.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is good idea to do it on the server side. What is your sql version?

Comment: You can define your table as `[colname] [time] NOT NULL DEFAULT CONVERT(time(7), getdate(), 108)`

Comment: I tried this and got the same error.

Comment: You can't get java exception in sql server.

Comment: @Hamlet that definition won't help. He wants to insert the row with a start time that happened before the time of insert, rather than insert the row then later perform an update.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I changed how the table is created per your suggestion. But when I run audit.setDate(4, new java.sql.Date(start.getTime())); I get the same error.

Comment: What is `4`, the column ordinal position? Have you considered using a stored procedure or a properly parameterized `INSERT` statement and just passing your parameter values, instead of all kinds of seemingly unnecessary scaffolding for things like `setDate()` - which is clearly treating your date/time value as a string in some way?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the SQL Server [`getdate()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx) function:

```
update Audit set StartTime=getdate(), . . . where . . .
```

or

```
insert into Audit (StartTime, . . .) values (getdate(), . . .)
```

Comment: There is a java method that runs, I want to insert a row with the start time and the end time at this time. if I use getDate() wont it just get the time at the time of row insertion?

Comment: Correct. To use `getdate()` you would have to do an insert to set the start time and then an update to set the end time - probably not the best thing...

Comment: Much of the required data for insert can't be inserted until the method finishes.